# React defaultProps doesn't fill missing object props

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

If I have a component that its propTypes are the following

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import propTypes from 'prop-types'

class MyComponent extends Component {
    ///
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
    hidden: propTypes.string.isRequired,
    items: propTypes.object,
    attributes: propTypes.array
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
    hidden: false,
    items: {},
    attributes: ['baz', 'qux']
}
```

If my component is called like this

`<MyComponent hidden={true} items={[value: 'foo', label: 'bar']} />`

I would like to expect that `props.attributes` is populated with the `defaultProps` values since it's value is not defined. Is this something that can be achieved (easily)?

Comment: what is not working? For me, looks like you are doing it right. It isn't a typo?

Comment: Works fine here: https://codesandbox.io/s/default-props-99vzd

Comment: You need to use double braces, like this:

change items from items={[value: 'foo', label: 'bar']}   to items={{value: 'foo', label: 'bar'}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [this example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-default-props-z5hci).

Your code ir working fine!

Take a look to see if it's not a typo or something like that.

Also take a look at your prop types.

Why the default of `hidden` is `false`, but the prop type is `string.isRequired` ?

You probably have errors on your console and that can cause the problems with `defaultProps`.

Answer (score 1):

Its working !! , check the code snippet below :

you may have error because you need to pass items as object as

```
items: {value: 'foo', label: 'bar'}
```

1. you need to import proptypes

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

2. you need to call this.props.attributes to access the default prop not supplied

```js
'use strict';

const e = React.createElement;
const propTypes = PropTypes;

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {
  console.log(this.props)
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.';
    }
const props = JSON.stringify(this.props)
    return e('div', null, `I have received these props : ${props}`)
  }
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
    hidden: propTypes.string.isRequired,
    items: propTypes.object,
    attributes: propTypes.array
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
    hidden: false,
    items: {},
    attributes: ['baz', 'qux']
}


const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
ReactDOM.render(e(MyComponent, {hidden: true ,items: {value: 'foo', label: 'bar'}}), domContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.6/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this looks fine for me ! Maybe there is another error in your console ?

this is the same, but could you try to add the propTypes and the defaultProps inside the component like the following :

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    ....
  };
    static defaultProps = {
    ....
  };
}
```